# Hidden elements are getting visible by inspecting

Tags: jquery, html, css, display

I have changed the CSS of an element that is both display:none 
and visibility hidden by jQuery but when I inspect them they are getting 
visible. Why?

Comment: By `getting visible` you mean visible in DOM or what?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, your question is not clear.

Comment: what did u mean by getting visible?? All html tags and elements are visible in inspect elements area. eg: if u take hidden input it doesn't visible in page but when u inspect it, u see it and its properties etc.

Comment: for eg i hidden the <a> tag it works fine until we inspect all hidden dom will be visible

Comment: you can delete hidden elements and To delete a node, you must call https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild, it's not a method of the document. It does not matter whether it's a hidden element or not

function removeElement(el) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want that element anymore on your view page then you should use ".remove()" method on that dom element.

If you want it to toggle in between show and hide without showing dom under inspection you can use ".empty()" to clear the content (or .remove() to remove them parmanetly) and add them later using ".html()". which will work in same way as display : none and display : inline without showing them while inspecting.

Answer (score 0):

They are so because css is part of static website designing and 'Inspect element' option allows you modify client-side data the way you want it. If you want them to be hidden, try using more of server-side functions for 'not sending the hidden elements' rather than 'sending the elements and hiding them'.If you planning on using only css, there is no way around to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks bro so if there is no way around? i just wanted to hidden the extra navigation of slider as i want only 6 nav but i have 9 items so i used this

Answer (score 0):

Any Element, which is loaded in **Dom can be visible by inspecting the Element**. If you want to avoid showing the Visible hidden DATA in Dom, Then you need to handle from Server Side using php,node.js, jsp and other server side programing languages